# TF.exe Git Permission Authentication Issue

Tags: git, powershell, tfs

I am trying to create a script that adds `CreateBranch` permissions to my repos in **Azure DevOps**. I am able to do login and run my git commands from **Powershell**, but when it comes time to use `tf.exe`, I get authentication errors. This is what I have setup so far:

```
tf.exe git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:[$project]\Contributors /collection:https://dev.azure.com/$organization/ /teamproject:$project /repository:$reponame
```

Here is my tf.exe.config for my proxy settings:

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

And when I run my script, I get the following error:

> Setting branch policies
>
> TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server
>   https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION. Technical information (for
>   administrator):   Unable to connect to the remote server

I have been circulating Google and Bing for the past couple of days and I have not been able to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you access https://dev.azure.com/$organization/ from browser on same machine where you are running this command?

Comment: @scorpio yes I can

Comment: Just want to check that at run-time of your script the $organization variable is getting replaced with correct value or not? sometimes typo in variables and empty/incorrect value can make problem visible differently!

Comment: @scorpio Yes I made sure. I had the whole statement printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of issue usually indicate there is some network issue which caused the connection failed.

An unexpected error occurred on a send. Hadn't succeed to use tf command behind a proxy.

Please first remove the proxy setting in your environment and specify `/login` parameter when using that tf.exe git permission command  `/login:FabrikamUser@hotmail.com,FabrikamPassword`

If you are using Personal Access Token, you could also specify `/login:PAT Token`

You could also follow comment's suggestion directly access dev.azure.com/$organization from browser on same machine where you are running this command. It will help to narrow down if issue related to your network environment or `tf.exe` command side.

Comment: If you insist on using a proxy with tf command, you could also take a look at Martin Woodward's blog here:http://www.woodwardweb.com/tfs_top_tip/tfs_top_tip_12.html Even it seems a little old, which may do the  trick.

Comment: Actually, this is not working... I don't understand what is not working. In Powershell, I can run all my git commands with no problem. The moment I use the tf.exe app to add my git permissions, I get these errors. It's like it's not using the proxy or it doesn't detect it

Comment: @NerdinTraining Actually I also didn't find any configuration or settings show how to use tf.exe command behind a proxy after go through official  docs. Never heard similar  situation before. Suggest you to  give a test with the same `tf git permission command` which work  without a proxy. If it works properly, then tf command may not be able to use the proxy or detect/work with it as you already pointed out.

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to set my proxy settings in tf.exe.config. I can't find anything online. Pretty frustrating!

Comment: Hi Nerd, how did your set your proxy in your local environment? TF command is actually located and installed with Team Explorer and Visual Studio. A suggestion, you could set your Visual Studio behind a proxy and then try to invoke the command again, which may do the trick.

Comment: Hi  Nerd in Training, hope you are doing well, any update on this ticket? Have you figured out your issue?

Comment: I maybe should have updated this, but it seems like I could not do it because of the proxy. I am now running my script from a Build.. I've run into other issues though. so I have that going for me :)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Done. Marked as answered